# How to add symbols to every file name in a folder?

Tags: file, directory, addition, rename

Let's say I have many files with an extension ".txd" in one folder. They all have different names and I want to add "_Q" to every file's name. I prefer if it would be at the end of the name. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what language? what os? what have you tried? did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Is it the good place to ask this question?

Comment: Any language is okay but it would be best if it was DOS batch. Windows 8.1 Pro. I did read it. Where else should I ask it?

Comment: maybe http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these [suggestions](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/), I think if none of the rest work the last one with the Bulk Rename Utility software will work for u. (You can download it and find a manual [here](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php))